# Moving a MySQL database from one computer to another computer

Tags: mysql

I am moving one database from one computer to another computer.
I have copied the folder from `Xampp > Mysql >Data > 'Database named folder'`  and placed in same location in new computer.

Now I am trying to access the tables of that database from new computer using `PHPMYADMIN` from browser and I am getting this error :

```
 #1932 - Table 'recoverydata.assignfeedback_editpdf_quick' doesn't exist in engine
```

Is there any more file that I need to copy? Or what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using Command Line Windows:

**Exporting the database**

1. Open up a Windows command prompt.
2. Change the directory to the following to access the mysqldump utility.

   cd \bin
3. Create a dump of your current mysql database or table (do not include the bracket symbols [ ] in your commands).
4. Run the `mysqldump.exe` program using the following arguments:

   ```
   mysqldump.exe –e –u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [database name] > C:\[filename].sql
   ```

If you supplied all the arguments properly, the program will connect to your current mysql server and create a dump of your whole database in the directory you specified in your C:\ directory. There is no message that will indicate the dump has been completed, the text cursor will simply move to the next line.
Here is an example of the command line syntax:

**Importing The Database** :

1. Go to the directory that the mysql client utility is located.

   ```
    cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
   ```
2. Import the dump of your database or table.
3. Run the `mysql.exe` program using the following arguments.

   ```
        mysql –u[user name] -p[password] -h[hostname] [database name] < C:\[filename].sql
   ```